# is IntStream class in JDK 1.6?

Tags: java

Is there any other class which and be use like `java.util.stream.IntStream` (of java 8) in  java 6

I wanted to achieve

```
  List<Integer> list = IntStream.of(intArray).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

how it is possible in java 6 or below

Comment: Not in the JDK directly, no. There might be some Guava implementation that does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want is to convert an `int[]` into an `List<Integer>`

you can either:

create your own ArrayList and add the elements manually

```
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(intArray.length);
    for(int value : intArray){
        list.add(value);
    }
```

Or you can easily write your own class that implements List using an primitive array backing:

```
public final class IntArrayList extends AbstractList<Integer> implements RandomAccess {

    private final int[] array;


    public IntArrayList(int[] array) {
        this.array = array;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer get(int index) {
        return array[index];
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return array.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer set(int index, Integer element) {
        Integer old = array[index];
        array[index] = element.intValue();
        return old;
    }

    public int indexOf(Object o) {
       if(o==null){
           return -1;
       }
       if(!(o instanceof Integer)){
           return -1;
       }
       int val = ((Integer)o).intValue();

        for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
            if (val==array[i]){
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        return indexOf(o) != -1;
    }
    /**
     * Optimization of equals since
     * we know we are have an array of ints
     * this should reduce boxing/unboxing
     * on our end at least.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == this){
            return true;
        }
        if (!(o instanceof List)){
            return false;
        }

        int currentOffset=0;
        ListIterator e2 = ((List) o).listIterator();
        while(currentOffset<array.length && e2.hasNext()) {
            Object o2 = e2.next();
            //will return false if o2 is null
            if(!(o2 instanceof Integer)){
                return false;
            }
            if(array[currentOffset] !=((Integer)o2).intValue()){
                return false;
            }
            currentOffset++;
        }
        return !(currentOffset<array.length || e2.hasNext());
        }

        /**
         * Optimization of hashcode since
         * we know we have an array of ints.
         */
        public int hashCode() {
            return Arrays.hashCode(array);
        }

}
```

And then it's just

```
 List<Integer> list = new IntArrayList(intArray);
```

Answer (score 4):

No, there's no simple way to do this in JDK6, that's exactly why they added it in JDK8.

You can either:

1. iterate over the `int` array and add the numbers one by one to the new collection

   ```
   int[] intArray = { 1,2,3 };
   List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<>(intArray.length);

   for (int i : intArray) {
       ints.add(i);
   }
   ```
2. or you can reach out for a library to do this for you. For example, Guava does this pretty well: [`Ints.asList()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html#asList(int...))

Comment: yap its there in Guava (just checked) but just to convert array to list can not add library

Comment: Sure. You should use it for all the other stuff it provides, too :). Anyway, if you don't need such functionality, you can easily do this by hand.